# Unresolved symbol on DLL loadup

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I am loading a DLL from an application and I want the DLL to be able to use a function implemented in the application. The definition of the function is put in a header and is included in the DLL. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here or whether this can't be done? Thanks for any help.

App:

```
include <API.h>

extern "C" int Mult(int x, int y)
{
    return x*y;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
if(argc <= 1)
    return -1;

void * pHandle = dlopen(argv[1], RTLD_NOW);
if(pHandle == NULL)
{
    cout << "Can't find DLL : " << argv[1] << endl;
    cout << dlerror() << endl;
    return -2;
}
else
    cout << "DLL Loaded" << endl;
```

The API.h file:

```
#ifndef __APP_API__
#define __APP_API__

extern "C" int Mult(int x, int y);

#endif
```

And the DLL:

```
#include <API.h>

int Imp1::GetFunctionID()
{
   return Mult(42, 42);
}
```

When run, this gives me the error:

Can't find DLL : ./ll.d.so
./ll.d.so: undefined symbol: Mult

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should instruct your compiler to put all the symbols of your executable (App) in it's dynamic symbol table. Otherwise, as Marcus Lindblom said, the dependencies would be one way only. With g++, the option is `-rdynamic`.

Comment: I have compiled my application with -rdynamic.

Comment: Well, it works for me with the command `g++ -shared lib.cpp -o lib.so && g++ -rdynamic app.cpp -ldl -o app && ./app ./lib.so`.

Comment: I build from a tool, and it has -fPIC flag on. When I tried to build in your way, I got the error:
`/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.3/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: /tmp/ccgUhY4M.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `__gxx_personality_v0' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC`
Does this have anything to do with whats happenning?

Comment: Again, it still works for me if I replace `-shared` by `-shared -fPIC` on the command I gave you.

Comment: Yes it does work for me if i build manually. Are there any flags that can cause problems?

Comment: This is app build directive: `g++  -ggdb -m64 -D BIG_ENDIAN=1  -Wall -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-qual -D _LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D LITTLE_ENDIAN=0 -D _REENTRANT -rdynamic -fPIC -imacros`

Comment: Not sure. The important thing is to have `-rdynamic` when compiling the app. Try the command `nm -D app | grep ' T '`: it will list the functions exported by the app and available to the lib. Normally this list is empty unless the app is compiled with `-rdynamic`, in which case you should see your `Mult` function.

Comment: I tried your build command. I had to remove `-m64` (I have a 32 bit box) and `-imacros` (which is for include files). I also added `app.cpp -ldl -o app`, obviously. With these amendments it still works for me...

Comment: This is funny. I see everything except Mult.

     0000000000402573 T OnError
0000000000402579 T OnWarning
0000000000403068 T _fini
0000000000402168 T _init
0000000000403058 T naedhsd_dummy`

OnError and OnWarning are two functions needed to be implemented due to a lib I have added.

Comment: Maybe `-rdynamic` is broken in your compiler? You may try `-Wl,--export-dynamic` instead, which should do the same. Check the man pages to see if `-rdynamic` is actually supported by your version of gcc (and `man ld` for `--export-dynamic`).

Comment: Oh! I just thought about it! If you are compiling app.cpp into an object file, `-rdynamic` should be used in the link phase: `g++ -rdynamic app.o -ldl -o app`

Comment: On a side note, why should rdynamic be a linker flag for executable but not dll?

Comment: @nakiya: `-rdynamic` is implied when compiling a shared object.